# What is the most efficient way to filter this dataframe based on a list of items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following format:

```
ORDER_NUMBER | PRODUCT1 | PRODUCT2  | PRODUCT3  | ...
ORDER1       | 1.0      | 0.0       | 0.0       | ...
ORDER2       | 0.0      | 0.0       | 0.0       | ...
ORDER3       | 0.0      | 1.0       | 0.0       | ...
ORDER4       | 0.0      | 0.0       | 0.0       | ...
ORDER5       | 0.0      | 1.0       | 1.0       | ...
...
```

In essence, I have one-hot encoded all products per order so that it is clear that, e.g., ORDER1 contains PRODUCT1, but not PRODUCT2 and PRODUCT3, etc.

I also have a list of products that I am interested in, for example:

```
interesting_products = ['PRODUCT1', 'PRODUCT3']
```

What I want to do is to keep ***only*** the orders (rows) where the products in my `interesting_products` list appear at least once (i.e., there's a '1.0' instead of '0.0').

So the resulting dataframe should be:

```
ORDER_NUMBER | PRODUCT1 | PRODUCT2  | PRODUCT3  | ...
ORDER1       | 1.0      | 0.0       | 0.0       | ...
ORDER5       | 0.0      | 1.0       | 1.0       | ...
...
```

My problem is that that this file is ***huge*** (a few GBs). What is the most efficient way of filtering my dataframe?

Comment: "appear at least once" is what I am looking for, hopefully, @jezrael will correct the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum` only columns by list and test if equal `1` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df[interesting_products].sum(axis=1).ne(0)]
```

Comment: @JonSG Good catch! Hopefully, OP will correct the answer.